# How to reduce the size of Flexdashboards

Tags: performance, size, flexdashboard

Including a lot of **charts and tables** can result in a big flexdashboard html file. Are there any **good practises to reduce the size** and / or optimise (e.g. linking instead of embedding) ?

Comment: try `self_contained: false` option fro flex_dashboard in yaml header of your Rmd file

Answer (score 2):

Got an [answer](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/211#issuecomment-462643362) after 30 mins - the R community is awesome !!! 
**self_contained: false** will do the trick

Comment: I tried `self_contained: false` which did reduce the html size, but when I email the html to an external partner, it doesn't load. Presumably because they can't load the resource folder. But I can't send that resource folder to a non-technical client. Suggestions?

Comment: hey, Cassandra, did you ever solve this problem?