# Knit Flexdashboard and exporting the used libraries to a different folder

Tags: html, r, flexdashboard

I think it's easier to explain what I need while giving you another example.
It is possible to export plotly graphs in R and saving the used libraries to a different folder using e.g. htmlwdigets::saveWidget.

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(fig, "path", libdir = "./lib")
```

Is there a way to knit my flexdashboard as a html while exporting the used libraries to a different folder?

Why I want to do this: We want to embed the flexdashboard into a website but the loading takes too long because its 24MB big. Our first idea was to somehow exclude the libraries and save them on the website, so they don't load every single time the website is refreshed. (I myself don't know a lot about websites, I only work on the R part here)
Shiny is not used for the dashboard if that makes any difference.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Honestly, I think this is what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643852/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-flexdashboards/54645432#comment134615718_54645432 But if there's any other solutions to quickly and drastically improve the performance of a flexdashboard, please let me know :)